# PWM phase voltage and current measurement for power consumption calculation for a BLDC MOTOR

Tags: pwm, brushless-dc-motor, three-phase, efficiency

I have been trying to log both voltage and current from the battery of an electric two wheeler for finding out efficiency at inverter, battery level.

Comment: So what have you done and what don't you know how to do?

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: I want to know, measure the power consumption of my 3 phase BLDC motor , I have been getting a very noisy  signals when I tried measuring current using a shunt and voltage drain from the battery

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 its 60v 20ah supply , motor (250watts). Power consumption from the battery, which I calculated turned out to be as high as 2000watts.

Comment: Do you have a problem using shielded twisted pairs using an INA? with ground shld terminated only at ADC.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I am using a lemo cable for getting the voltage and current output from the battery

Comment: Can you use a 2 milliohm shunt then use Ferrite clamshells around cable then INA terminated in 120 Ohms. with  1k gain  to reduce noise?  For Voltage use a LPF, 10kHz or to measure battery ripple, ac couple into 50 Ohms.

Comment: e.g. https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/INA103KP/INA103KP-ND/251070 use gain =100 then 2nd stage if you want 3V to 5V max

Comment: I am not very good at electronics...At the moment ,I am using a DAQ system which can log up to 400k sampling rate;

Comment: Could you explain me in simpler terms if possible

Comment: Inverter carrier frequency is around 10 - 15khz

Comment: Try putting 120 Ohm across current sense resistor at DAQ input to reduce noise.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75  Across the shunt resistor ? Which is used to measure current ...can you give me a logical reason for doing so

Comment: You are picking up noise between the current shunt and your DAQ. the cable is unshielded and probably unbalanced and picking up commutation noise like an antenna as you indicated. Terminating the cable in 120 Ohms is about the cable impedance will reducing ingress and ringing in it. Since youhave no idea how to do a proper instrument measurement without noise, this is the easiest 1st step

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I will give it a shot Tomo morning

Comment: @also Motors are supposed to handle peaks of up to 10x rated power during starts, so your battery ESR and FET switch Ron both must be < 10% of motor DCR for 10% peak losses and 1% steady state max load.  and all these specs should be in your question along with Signal/Noise ratio as a problem or for charging same Source ESR << load ESR

Answer (score 1):

If you have a scope available you can look at the input and determine if you have noise or if the problem is with your sense circuit. You could also try to add some capacitors on the input this might fix your problem if noise is the issue. You can also use an multimeter to determine if your current measurements are correct or you can invest in an VESC which can log power at both the input and output.